# How can I create custom mouse actions in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse

My mouse has 2 additional buttons at the side. The mouse's default driver doesn't have many functions.

I want to set it so that if one of the buttons is pressed, the other buttons (including right click and left click) will have different functions. For example, if the button is pressed, then the right click button can cause WMP to skip to the next song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I like X-mouse,](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) but you still have to have the mouse driver for your particular mouse installed for X-mouse (or any other software) to see the additional buttons.

X-mouse has many more options than most all mouse drivers, highly configurable.

Posting your mouse model would be helpful also.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use AHK ([AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)) you can find a lot of help in their forums as well.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  A hint in the right direction, like mentioning a tool, is more appropriate as a comment.  An answer should be an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed windows7 , the mouse driver for my multibutton input devices was not fully supported.   I found this 3rd party DonateWare called "X-Mouse Button Control" http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm   it has most of the same functions the software had, plus a few more. It will work for 5 button mouses (or trackballs).  It installs as a Hook.

I just use the stock mouse driver that MS supplied with the system, but my mouse is still a PS2 type.

I am often setting a "keyboard" actions to occur on the mouse button press.  So the next thing you need is a list of media player shortcut keys http://www.technoweblog.com/featured/shortcut-keys-for-windows-media-player-11

Also Autohotkey can be usefull.